# Convert Raw SQL query to Laravel DB Query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following raw SQL query:

```
select a.id user_id, a.email_address, a.name_first, a.name_last, count(b.id) number_of_videos, sum(b.vimeo_duration) total_duration, sum(b.count_watched) total_playbacks
  from users a,
       videos b
 where a.id = b.tutor_id
   and a.email_address in ('candace_rennie@yahoo.com', 'tjm@hiltoncollege.com', 'matthewjameshenshall@gmail.com', 'nkululeko@syafunda.co.za', 'khulile@syafunda.co.za', 'nzakheni@syafunda.co.za')
 group by a.id;
```

This correctly gets 6 rows from the database. I'm trying to convert this to a Laravel database query like so:

```
$totals = DB::table('users')
                    ->select(DB::Raw('users.id as user_id'), 'users.email_address', 'users.name_first', 'users.name_last', DB::Raw('count(videos.id) as number_of_videos'), DB::Raw('sum(videos.vimeo_duration) as total_duration'), DB::Raw('sum(videos.count_watched) as total_playbacks'))
                    ->join('videos', 'users.id', '=', 'videos.tutor_id')
                    ->where('users.id', 'videos.tutor_id')
                    ->whereIn('users.email_address', array('candace_rennie@yahoo.com', 'tjm@hiltoncollege.com', 'matthewjameshenshall@gmail.com', 'nkululeko@syafunda.co.za', 'khulile@syafunda.co.za', 'nzakheni@syafunda.co.za'))
                    ->groupBy('users.id')
                    ->get();
```

This however return 0 rows. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: also try adding email_address, first_name, last_name in groupby clause.

Comment: Do you have models set up for these tables?

Answer (score 0):

It should be smth like below even tho `groupBy` user id does not help much as id is unique.

```
$aggregates = [
    DB::raw('count(b.id) as  number_of_videos'),
    DB::raw('sum(b.vimeo_duration) as  total_duration'),
    DB::raw('sum(b.count_watched) as total_playbacks'),
];

$simpleSelects = ['users.email_address', users.id, 'users.name_first', 'users.name_last'];

$emails = ['candace_rennie@yahoo.com', 'tjm@hiltoncollege.com'....]

$users = Users::select(array_merge($simpleSelects, $aggregates))
    ->leftJoin('videos as b', function ($join) use ($emails) {
        $join->on('b.tutor_id', 'a.id')
            ->whereIn('users.email_address', $emails);
    })
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line:

```
->where('users.id', 'videos.tutor_id')
```

Answer (score -1):

1. List item

   after sql code convert into laravel
2. DB::select('posts.id','posts.title','posts.body')

   ```
                                      ->from('posts')
                                   ->where('posts.author_id', '=', 1)
                                   ->orderBy('posts.published_at', 'DESC')
                                   ->limit(10)
                                   ->get();
   ```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here?